# How to Find all address name from osm that's imported into postgres

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

How can I get all address name from osm. in the schemas imported into postgres database. I have found. But none of them seem to contain a readily available address, which I can easily select. What can I do?

```
 public | geometry_columns   | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_line    | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_nodes   | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_point   | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_polygon | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_rels    | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_roads   | table | postgres
 public | planet_osm_ways    | table | postgres
 public | spatial_ref_sys    | table | postgres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DB schema you are refering to, is [produced by osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema) as part of the [OSM rendering stack](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Components). So it's tuned for the purpose of drawing maps.

To search for an address (called **geocoding**) is a completely different use of geodata that needs different DB schemas/datastructures. Furthermore, you need to do preprocess and clean of OSM raw data to create hierachies (e.g. continent-country-county-city-street-housenumber) etc.
At OSM the [nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) tool is used for such kind of purposes and is recommend for (reverse)geocoding.

Comment: Is there any scalable way of doing this? 'case I have massive of data to fetch addresses

Comment: Nominatim is scalable like the most webservices, but of course you need the ressources. If you like to do bulk requests on public infrastructure, please respect the policies and do the requests over a long period.

Comment: Nominatim is not scalable because it doesn't support remote databases. Meaning each instance of the service needs a local copy of the DB.